# Orika mapper spring boot doesn't map when I define a CustomMapper

Tags: spring-boot, orika

I have the following structure:

Controller (model classes) -> service -> (domain classes) repository.

This is what I do in the **service layer** when I have to persist something coming into the request body:

- Map the model class (coming from the body request) into the domain class (Trying to use Orika)
- Persist the domain class and after getting an OK from the DB
- map the domain class saved in the DB into the model class (Trying to use Orika)
- return back the response to the controller

This is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
@Component
public class CustomMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {
private MapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

@Override
protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
    System.out.println("Spring boot mapper initializing.....");
    factory.classMap(ModelSource.class, ModelDestination.class)
            .byDefault()
            .register();

}
```

I can see the message "Spring boot mapper initializing....." running spring boot so that means the component is loading OK.

```
@Autowired
private CustomMapper mapperFacade;

ModelDestination destination = mapperFacade.map(ModelSource.class, ModelDestination.class);
```

When I check all the destination fields, they are all null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The problem is that I have defined a array of String in each class private String[] chain;. It's the same name in both source and destination but for some reason doesn't work. It works if a define a string var for example, the problem is the array of string

Answer (score 0):

Using the last Orika version 1.5.4. This fixed my issue:

```
            .field("chain{}", "chain{}")
```